# Authorization based on OASIS ABAC/RBAC/XACML approach

Tags: .net, rbac, abac, xacml

Is anybody aware of any open source .NET authorization solution based on OASIS ABAC/RBAC/XACML approach?

I have found some visible amount of Java based solutions but it seems .NET is completely out of it (lack of interest, not in trend?).

What does .NET community use then to implement Attribute or Role based authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are (have been) several commercial implementations on .NET:

- Bitkoo (acquired by Quest then Dell, now defunct)
- ViewDS (Australian-based, integrated with their virtual directory)
- [Axiomatics](https://www.axiomatics.net/blog/entry/custom-claims-based-authorization-in-net-using-axiomatics-pep-sdk-for-net.html) (both Java and .NET) (disclaimer - I work there)

In the open-source space, there are definitely more Java engines than .NET engines but that is likely due to the nature of the languages. Java is more prevalent than C#. There is even a [PHP project](https://github.com/enygma/xacmlphp) for XACML.

[image: Open Source Languages] ([Source](https://www.slideshare.net/blackducksoftware/open-source-by-the-numbers))

That said, the implementation language shouldn't really matter to you. XACML offers *authorization as a service* that sits within your infrastructure and can be easily consumed from multiple languages. XACML defines a [REST/JSON interface](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/xacml-json-http/v1.0/xacml-json-http-v1.0.html) which you can easily use.